# Infinite Catch in Reactive Extenions

Tags: .net, rx-java, system.reactive, reactive-programming

My question relates to Rx and Catch operator. Lets say I have Timeout on my observable and each time timeout occurs I would like to recreate underlying observable (Catch) and do the same thing (add timeout and catch).

Below I pasted example code. For purpose of this example Timeout occurs all the time every 2 seconds. From my observation this code can't work infinitely, somehow after recreation something is holding reference to old observable leftovers. Those leftovers accumulate all the time when Catch is called.

Most suspicious line is the last one, were some kind of self-reference is present. But I can't actually visualise myself why it might be wrong? Also is there any way to create observable with similar logic that will work forever?

```
    public static IObservable<string> CreateReliableStream(this IObservable<string> targetObservable, Func<IObservable<string>> recreateObservable)
    {
        return targetObservable
            .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
            .Catch<string, Exception>(exception => ReconnectOnError(exception, recreateObservable));
    }

    private static IObservable<string> ReconnectOnError(Exception exception, Func<IObservable<string>> recreateObservable)
    {
        GC.Collect(); // For debug - make sure all unreferenced object are removed

        return recreateObservable()
            .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
            .Catch<string, Exception>(ex => ReconnectOnError(ex, recreateObservable));
    }
```

Comment: Is this a .net question or a Java question? I'm confused by the rx-java tag...

Comment: This is more Rx question so rx-net and rx-java are fine. Only code example  is in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to use the `Retry()` operator.

I assume your initial sequence is the same as your continuation sequence.

e.g.

```
Observable.Return(1).Concat(Observable.Throw<int>(new Exception()))
    .Retry()
```

That will run in a tight infinite loop.

Your code might end up looking like

```
createObservable()
    .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
    .Retry()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
//done in Linqpad, where async Main is allowed.
async void Main() 
{
    var source = new Subject<string>();
    var backup = new Subject<string>();
    var reliableStream = source.CreateReliableStream(() => backup);
    reliableStream.Subscribe(s => Console.WriteLine($"Next: {s}"), e => Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Message}"), () => Console.WriteLine("Completed."));

    source.OnNext("sourceAbc");
    backup.OnNext("backupAbc");
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.5));

    source.OnNext("sourceDef");
    backup.OnNext("backupDef");
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.5));

    //Doesn't yield "Completed" because it's re-subscribing.
    source.OnCompleted();
    backup.OnCompleted();

}

public static class Ex
{
    public static IObservable<string> CreateReliableStream(this IObservable<string> targetObservable, Func<IObservable<string>> recreateObservable)
    {
        return targetObservable
            .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
            .Catch<string, Exception>(exception => ReconnectOnError(exception, recreateObservable));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IObservable<T>> InfiniteObservables<T>(Func<IObservable<T>> f)
    {
        while(true)
            yield return f();
    }

    private static IObservable<string> ReconnectOnError(Exception exception, Func<IObservable<string>> recreateObservable)
    {
        GC.Collect(); // For debug - make sure all unreferenced object are removed

        return InfiniteObservables(recreateObservable)
            .Select(o => o.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)))
            .OnErrorResumeNext();
    }
}
```

Yields the following output:

```
Next: sourceAbc
Next: sourceDef
Next: backupHij
Next: backupLmn
```

I'm not a fan of this approach though. Rx treats errors like stream-terminators, and you're trying to treat them like an alternate message. You'll end up swimming up-river like this.